# Android. OutOfMemory error on bitmap creation inside observable when rotate

Tags: android, bitmap, rx-java

I have an activity with `imageView`. When I rotate device `onCreate` starts creating bitmap inside the background thread. After several rotations I have a `OutOfMemoryError` on the bitmap creation.
What is a the correct way to fix this? Is there a decision with `weak references`? 
Here is my code:

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Disposable imageDisp;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        imageDisp.dispose();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_imageview);

        String source = getIntent().getStringExtra("source");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setTag(source);

        imageDisp = Observable.fromCallable(()->{
            File outputFile = new File(source);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFile.getPath(), options); // here I have a outOfMemory
            outputFile.delete();
            return b;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(bitmap -> {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imageView.setOnTouchListener(ImageActivity.this);
                },
                throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(throwable.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the size of your bitmap? Maybe you should downscaled it with Bitmap Options inSampleSize?

Comment: I need a big image in my activity. it's about 5mp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how correct it is, but this works:

```
imageDisp = Observable.fromCallable(()->{
            System.gc();
            final WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmapReference = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFile.getPath(), options));
            outputFile.delete();
            return bitmapReference;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(bitmap -> {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get());
                            imageView.setOnTouchListener(ImageActivity.this);
                },
                throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(throwable.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Comment: I know how correct it is - not at all. 1) `System.gc()` - this will freeze your whole app for some time. You should never call it. 2)  `WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmapReference` - You have created weak reference to object what you need in near future (`subscribe()`). In some scenarios, return value of `bitmap.get()` might be null. 

There is no leak happen, you basically load too big photos. You've mentioned you need to show 5MPX photos (2560x1920) - do you test on phone with 2k display? Otherwise you don't need that big images.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. I'll try to decrease the size of a picture.